# Install android wear app on iPhone

Tags: iphone, wear-os

I've developed an app for android wear that has an handheld side and a wear side.

Is it possible to install an android wear app through android wear installed on the iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, currently that is not supported.

Comment: Thanks dude, always helpful!